# postgres script troubles syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: database, bash, function, postgresql

I am missing something below. I keep getting unexpected end of file. What is it?

```
function lock_inactive_accounts {
    echo "Locking inactive accounts or accounts that haven't logged in during the past 35 days."
    echo " "
    echo "The following accounts have been locked: "
    su - postgres -c "psql database" << EOF
      UPDATE users SET has_locked_account = true WHERE DATE_PART('days', now() - last_successful_login) > 35;
      SELECT name from users where has_locked_account = 't';
        EOF
}

lock_inactive_accounts
```

Comment: For your own convenience you can consider running problematic snippets like this through shellcheck to get instant feedback on many common problems (including this one)

Comment: shellcheck, awesome. I never knew about this! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the terminating `EOF` should be at the beginning of the line for *here document* to work:

```
su - postgres -c "psql database" <<EOF
  UPDATE users SET has_locked_account = true WHERE DATE_PART('days', now() - last_successful_login) > 35;
  SELECT name from users where has_locked_account = 't';
EOF
```

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to make a difference within a function.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is correct regardless. Maybe `<< EOF`. Or the tab-friendly syntax, which I vaguely recollect being `<<-EOF` or something to that order.

Comment: I just checked by copying your (not mine) code above, putting it into a script (no sharp-bang), making sure `EOF` is starting at column 1, and running (in Linux) and it does work: 

Locking inactive accounts or accounts that haven't logged in
            during the past 35 days.
 
The following accounts have been locked: 
su: must be run from a terminal